# Qt GUI C++ global declaration fault

Tags: c++, qt, variables, header, declaration

I have a problem adding global variables. I tried declaring them in a separate header file, called "declare_struct.h" I included the .h in the .cpp and still can't refer to the variables and I keep getting error messages when I am trying to use them in a function in the header file.

This is what's in the header:

````
#define DECLARE_STRUCT_H

#include <QString>
#include <QVector>
#include <QRegularExpression>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>



extern QString helper_quest, helper_a, helper_b, helper_c, helper_d, helper_good;

class Question
{
public:
    Question();public:
    QString quest, answer_a, answer_b, answer_c, answer_d, answer_good;
};

extern Question q;
extern QVector<Question> quiz;

void load (QString filename)
{
    quiz.clear();
    QRegularExpression re_Q("Q: ");
    QRegularExpression re_A("A: ");
    QRegularExpression re_B("B: ");
    QRegularExpression re_C("C: ");
    QRegularExpression re_D("D: ");
    QRegularExpression re_Ans("Ans: ");


    QString trash, need;
    QFile inf(filename);

  ///  if (inf.good())
   /// {
  ///      getline(inf, trash); ///deletes the title of the questionnaire
  ///  }

    for (int i =0; i<10; i++)
    {
        QTextStream in(&inf);

        q.quest = in.readLine();
        q.quest.remove(re_Q);

        q.answer_a = in.readLine();
        q.answer_a.remove(re_A);

        q.answer_b = in.readLine();
        q.answer_b.remove(re_B);

        q.answer_c = in.readLine();
        q.answer_c.remove(re_C);

        q.answer_d = in.readLine();
        q.answer_d.remove(re_D);

        q.answer_good = in.readLine();
        q.answer_good.remove(re_Ans);

        quiz.push_back(q);


    }
}

#endif // DECLARE_STRUCT_H    ```

in the declare_struct.cpp :
``` #include "declare_struct.h"

Question::Question()
{

}
```

And I keep getting the following errors:
[errors][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyerL.png
````

Comment: ***I have a problem adding global variables*** Why are you doing that in the first place?

Comment: `void load (QString filename)` Why did you implement `load()` in a header?

Comment: Maybe you should have a `Quiz` class containing a vector of `Question`? And the `Quiz` class would handle the loading.

Comment: I want to use the load() function in more .cpp files. Where do you think I should implement it then?

Comment: How exactly do you mean the Quiz class? I’m not sure I understand it

Comment: The implementation of load() should be in a .cpp file, the variables either local variables, or member variables of some class (e.g. `Quiz`)